# Using a Copper Waterblock or Aluminum Heatsink to Cool Water via Thermo Electric Cooler

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I am attempting to create a ThermoElectric Cooler to Chill Water. I have thought of two options as to how I can cool the water:

Some limitations of the design:

- The water is still, not moving. No "PVC water pipes" can be used.

1) Running the still water through a copper water block, as shown below.

- I would have the Peltier cool the waterblock, which would then take water from the top and cool. Nothing would be pumped in, water would freely exit and enter the holes from the top and exit without any assistance. **(design limitations)**.

[image]

2) Having the water touch an aluminum heatsink

- I would have the Petier cool the aluminum heatsink and simply have the water run through the grills of the cooled heatsink .

[image]

**Question**:

Given the above designs, which would be more efficient at cooling water? Having water seep into the waterblock, or have water run along the grills of the aluminum heatsink? This is given the water is still, no pipes to funnel in water to the waterblock just gravity.

Comment: So what, specifically, is your question? This sounds like a “naive design” question, which is off-topic according to the help centre

Comment: @JonathanRSwift let me try to make it more clear, give me a second

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I updated my question

Comment: You say the water is still, but then both your options have the water moving: "water **seep** into the waterblock" and "water **run** along the grills". Please clarify.

Comment: @Wasabi All I mean by this is that the water simply just touches through gravity the heatsink/water block. As in, it just touches without moving, or in the case of the waterblock just runs through the holes with no additional force.