# How to Pull Heat Quicker from a Thermo-Electric Cooler using an Aluminum Heatsink

Tags: heat-transfer

I just purchased an aluminum heatsink that I am using to "wick" away heat from a Peltier; however, I was wondering how I can pull heat from the hot side of the peltier quicker.

I have purchased large, small, medium sized aluminum heatsinks and have not been able to explain why one works better than the other. This is the root of the problem: what determines how fast a heatsink can wick heat away from the hotside of the Peltier? 
[image]

I was thinking adding copper heat pipes, such as the ones on a laptop heatsink-fan combinations; however, I would need to thermally attach the copper heatpipes to the same heatsink to cool them. I am afraid this might kill the efficiency of the heatsink.

Thank you, and I am looking forward to hearing your suggestions

Comment: given this question : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/21752/10902 perhaps you should consider some research on heat transfer theory i.e. conduction...

Comment: @SolarMike I've done a lot of research, just looking for someone to tell me: Yeah, that would be a good idea, or say: No, that wouldn't work because the efficiency decreases.

Comment: Did you use a thermal paste? The air gap between the radiator and the heat source, despite being micrometers wide, is a massive insulator.

Comment: @SF. Yes, I have thermal paste between the ThermoElectric Cooler and the Heatsource; however, I can't explain what makes this heatsink-fan combo poor in comparison to others that I have purchased. I was hoping for some way to increase the efficiency of this heatsink.

Comment: @omarsumadi: It boils down to surface area, air flow, and thermal conductivity of the materials (the paste is worse than the heatsink, so use as thin layer as necessary to replace the air gap). Also, ambient temperature and irradiation to a degree, and energy consumption of the fan motor. I think this is about complete list of factors.

Comment: @SF. Do you think putting copper heat pipes under the thermo electric cooler, then using thermal paste to connect the copper heat pipes to the aluminum would work better than just a heatsink?

Comment: @omarsumadi: Absolutely not. You want to maximize the contact surface between the heat source and the radiator. The pipes would only touch a minimal part of the surface and the paste is a lousy conductor. If the radiator is running hot though, you may use the pipes to drive heat to other radiators from it. Could you provide a photo or drawing of your rig?

Comment: @SF. It's literally just a ThermoElectric cooler thermally pasted ontop of this heat sink. That's it! Not the grandest, but I was looking for ways to suck more heat off the Thermo Electric cooler. I guess, just a higher quality aluminum and thermal paste is all that I can do? Are there any ways to suck heat away more efficiently in a small area using a different method?

Comment: @omarsumadi: Top? I'd think bottom. 1. Bigger sink = larger surface area. 2. Faster fan = higher air flow. 3. Use copper heatsink, copper conducts heat better than aluminum. If that''s still insufficient, consider water cooling. A water block (heat collector of copper with water channels through inside), a pump, and a large radiator (the sort used in car engines) to cool the water. And a fan to force air through that radiator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conductivity, surface area, and air flow are the major factors.

Some have a plastic funnel so the fan can be larger than the sink.

I assume (hope) you get better with larger heat sinks and fans.

A case fan also helps.

That looks like a relatively small fan.  I get full size cases for better cooling.